# std::make_shared<Type> creates memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, std, smart-pointers

Valgrind gives me some memory leaks when I use std::make_shared:

```
TEST_F(CTestChild, add_gran_child) {
    auto child{ std::make_shared<CChild>(TType::Home, std::make_shared<CMockParent>()) };
    NiceMock<CMockCaller> caller;
    auto gran_child( std::make_shared<CMockGranChild>(TType::Girl, child, caller) );
    child->Add(gran_child);
    EXPECT_EQ(child->GetCount(), 1);
}

class CMockParent : CParent{
public:
    void something(void) override {}
}

class CParent{
public:
    virtual void something(void) = 0;
}

class CChild{
public:
    CChild(TType, shared_ptr<CParent> a) : _parent(a) {}
    void Add(shared_ptr<CGranChild> a) { _list.push_back(a) }
    shared_ptr<CParent> _parent;
    TList<shared_ptr<CGranChild>> _list;
}

class CGranChild{
public:
    CGranChild(TType, shared_ptr<CChild> a) : i_parent(a) {}
    shared_ptr<CChild> _parent;
}
```

Why is make_shared giving me a memory leak?

Edit: I have included the summary of the classes for better understanding of the code.

Comment: Does a child store a shared_ptr to its parent, and vice versa ?

Comment: yes I am adding the classes overview so that maybe its more clear

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have 2 shared pointers owning each other.

think of a clear ownership concept. then store a `std::weak_ptr` in the non-owner. To access the non-owned object `.lock()` the weak_ptr and check the resulting shared_ptr before use.

Comment: ...or even use a raw pointer instead of the `weak_ptr` if you can guarantee that the owning object will always outlive the non-owning one.

Comment: I prefer the weak_ptr